# Copy range base on cell value to another worksheet, then delete entire row on the original worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to seek help on the codes I am doing. I already made to copy range (data) and move to another sheet, but I don't know to delete this range (or entire row) on the original worksheet.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked _.ClearContents_ or _.Clear_ of a range?

Comment: Sorry. I like to delete the entire row so that there will be no blank rows on the orig worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Please include the relevant portions of your code next time as well as anything you've already tried.

This is just the most obvious solution.  You may need something more complex but I have no way of knowing from your post.

Comment: This is my code so far

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With PRO
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("F2:F" & LstRw)
        For Each rng1 In rng.Cells
            If rng1 = "Pipeline" Then
                With PIP
                    Yr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End With
                .Range(.Cells(rng1.Row, "A"), .Cells(rng1.Row, "J")).Copy PIP.Range("A" & Yr)
                
            End If

        Next rng1
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub